# Samsung model UN22F5000AF will not pik up any channels when I scan with antenna only... Do not have cable

Tags: television

My 22" Samsung has an antenna hooked to it,  as my room has no cable outlet. However,  when I run Auto Scan,  it will not pick up a single channel. I was been looking online for an answer for hours and at this point am very frustrated. I did not have this problem in my previous apartment. I need help please!! Thank you

Comment: Do you have confirmation that where you live can receive channels? What kind of TV antenna do you have hooked to the TV (on the roof, in the attic, wall of the home, omni directional, or something like basic rabbit ears)? Do you have the TV setting set to ANTENNA instead of CABLE or SAT?

Comment: Yes to all of the above.. There r 2 DirectTv outlets in 2 rooms,  not a problem at all with those. Unfortunately there is no outlet in my room. I am using an anteena on the wall,  and my TV is set to Antenna. It scans,  but will not pick up a single channel.

Comment: Well, do you live in a densely populated area and "should be receiving" strong signal? Do you know if any neighbors have "rabbit ear" antennas and they work? I don't believe you should "say yes to every question" I asked. If you are or could be using direct TV in the home, but not at this TV, then it doesn't matter. If you have ANTENNA on another TV, please tell us if it is one that is OUTSIDE the home.

Comment: My line of questions above is to ascertain if you CAN use rabbit ears antenna and receive TV signal. Just because you hook an antenna up, doesn't mean you will get a signal, if you were in a cave or a lead room, it wouldn't work. Since you probably aren't, I'm trying to get a feel for how strong the TV signals in your area are so we can investigate if it is the TV, the Antenna, the connection and settings between the two, or if it is where the antenna is located.

Comment: The DirectTv dish is outside the home,  there is just not an outlet in my room. I am living with my very elderly parents who are not in good health and I have attempted to get them to have a outlet put in my room but they are not receptive to that idea. Yes this is a densely populated area Napa California and I believe for neighbors that I've talked to that they all have a form of cable not a surly DirecTV but they do have cable there are a lot of dishes outside in this Park that we live in. Anteenas worked perfect in my previous apt.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have tried different spots on the walls with antenna to see if we're have that was the problem to no avail. I know when I auto scan it comes up with air table and the third one is I can't remember but they're all set on STD of the one excuse me is sent on STD for for the air the other two are sent to HRC and IRC.

Comment: So let me be clear so to be sure we are on the same page, and I think we are. You are aware that Direct TV is NOT an Antenna type system like we are talking here. From the point of view of your TV, it is cable. Now, most areas have begun if not have completed changing over their analog broadcast signals to Digital broadcasts. So older television sets require a converter box. Your TV is not that old, you should not need one. So the next question is what surrounds your room? Are you in a wooden building? Is there anything above your room besides a roof? What is the roof made of?

Comment: You need "AIR" selected. HRC/IRC will not come in to play. Does your AIR setting have an Analog or Digital selection? I did not see that well described in the manual

Comment: Are you near Green Valley? Put your address in here: https://www.fcc.gov/media/engineering/dtvmaps

Comment: My AIR doesn't have an Analog or Digital selection. I'm in a large mobile home,  it isnt made of wood,  and my bedroom is surrounded by the hallway,  and there is nothing above my room but a traditional roof.

Comment: How old is the TV antenna you are using? Can you read a model number and manufacturer off of it?

Comment: I am in the Napa Valley,  9 miles north of Napa in Yountville

Comment: I did buy the anteena,  it fact it came with 2,  less than 3 months ago. Brand is Sobetter,  Model # is S010D.

Comment: Please go type your address in to the website I linked, you will see you are in an area that gets VERY WEAK SIGNAL. You don't have a single strong signal around you. Then go type NAPA, CA in and you will see a dozen. So what this is telling us is you need a substantial antenna to get service.

Comment: Thank you for all your help,  I can see from the link you sent that I virtually have no antenna signal. Can you recommend a very strong antenna I could use?

Comment: I cannot make this as a recommendation since I have not used it, but it is certainly a major step up from the antenna you currently use, and it can be mounted outside, which WILL help your odds of receiving a signal: http://www.homedepot.com/p/Antop-Flat-Panel-Outdoor-Indoor-HD-Multi-Directional-HDTV-Digital-TV-Antenna-with-High-Gain-AT-400/300489190

Comment: Oh, the antenna above is just a big box store one with high ratings, it has high gain, and is indoor and outdoor. You could try it INSIDE, but don't give up if you go this route... because you could mount it outside and have success. But doing so could mean installing a pole, and more wire, adding cost. Thus my recommendation below in my answer post.

Answer (score 1):

Based on our discussion amplifying the original question, the cut to the chase answer is: You are not getting any channels on your TV because there are no channels to receive.

Unfortunately, the above answer is the precise reason you are frustrated. You noted you did not have this problem where you lived before, that is most certainly because you lived in a better area for TV signal reception.

Using this map you can get a pretty good idea of what types of signals the FCC expects one would receive at any geographical location:
https://www.fcc.gov/media/engineering/dtvmaps

using that, type in any major city, or where you lived previously, then type in where you live today. As you see the number of channels drop off to near none, it gives you a solid feel for what you could expect to receive.

If you see channels on the list that are within your reach & interest, you can install a TV antenna. But this TV antenna will not be rabbit ears. As you have already tried an internal antenna to no success, you have to try different antenna options. You can try an omni-directional antenna, mounted on a pole, or on the roof You can try one outside of your window, but basically, the bigger (and bigger does not mean size) the antenna you use (which will be directly proportionate to cost, and time to install it) - the better odds you will have of receiving more signals.

I realize you mentioned there is direct TV in the home. I suspect an installer will charge between $30-$100 to install a new outlet in your room. Since you would have to install an outdoor antenna in either case, your best chances are to add to this service and pay the additonal cost for an added tuner box from Direct TV. I suspect the cost will be less in the short term. In teh long run, the Direct TV route will be more expensive since you will pay service charges and taxes, until, termination.